# Cshell script setting up a flag

Tags: shell

Currently I am doing this on my script..

```
if($notLoaded1 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors: $notLoaded1"
  exit 1
endif

if($notLoaded2 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors: $notLoaded2"
  exit 1
endif

if($notLoaded3 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors: $notLoaded3"
  exit 1
endif
```

How can i set up a flag so it won't exit on the first if statement, goes through all of them and lets me know like which other if statement had problem too.. Thank you.. Someone please help me with this .. I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

why not simply define a variable 'flag' and use the && operator setting it to 0 if you don't want to exit:

```
$flag && exit 1
```

Comment: Thanx for your help but I am new to this can you show it to me how can I change this existing lines to do that.. Thank you

Comment: could you help me with this i am just stuck with this.. i did this 'set flag

if($notLoaded1 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in first load: $notLoaded1"
  $flag && exit 0
endif

if($notLoaded2 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in second load: $notLoaded2"
  $flag && exit 0
endif

if($notLoaded3 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in third load: $notLoaded3"
  $flag && exit 0
endif' what else do i need to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set errorFlag=0
if ($notLoaded1 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors: $notLoaded1"
  set errorFlag=1
endif

if ($notLoaded2 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors: $notLoaded2"
  set errorFlag=1
endif

if ($notLoaded3 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors: $notLoaded3"
  set errorFlag=1
endif

if ($errorFlag != 0) then
  exit 1
endif
```

I don't have access to a csh environment now, so I can't test this. I'm not absolutely sure about the `!=` test, so you can also use `$errorFlag > 0`.

I hope this helps.